# Why am I getting "Unrecognized attribute 'Result" from gnat 4.4?

Tags: attributes, ada, pragma, gnat

I am getting compiler error, "Unrecognized attribute 'Result" from gnat 4.4.0 in my codes which contain the following:

```
   pragma Postcondition ( Kind ( Create_Object'Result ) = String_Type ) ;
```

I have checked the GNAT Reference Manual (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Pragma-Postcondition.html#Pragma-Postcondition). It says pragma Postcondition was implemented prior to Ada 2012 and was retained for compatibility purposes.

I am wondering why the error and how to get rid of it.

Can anyone provide some pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: Not definitive hence comment, but I suspect Gnat-4.4 is far too early to support pre/postconditions reliably. I recommend upgrading to at least Gnat-4.9 and using Ada-2012. Which platform are you using  (Someone may be able to suggest where to find a newer Gnat for that platform) Is there a specific problem tying you to Gnat-4.4? Someone may be able to suggest a solution.

Comment: I am running OS X 10.5 with Xcode 3.0. Not sure Gnat-4.9 will run on my old Mac or not.

Comment: I released GCC 4.6 at [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuada/files/GNAT_GCC%20Mac%20OS%20X/) in late 2011, so there may be some working Ada2012 features; but that was for Darwin 10, and you’re running Darwin 9. Maybe better luck with  GCC 4.7 (built for Lion, Darwin 11, OS X 10.7)? I can’t check the features, because none of those releases before GCC 4.8 runs on El Capitan (Darwin 15, OS X 10.11). GCC 4.8 appears to understand `’Result`.

Comment: My machine is too old for production but I would keep it for some light and experimental development that does not require Ada2012. I am still keeping the Xcode 3.0 for the Ada plugin. Love the Ada Xcode plugin so much. Anyway, I am trying to restart Ada development on El Capitan. The problem is that I have been away from Ada development for sometime and it's quite a hassle to patch things up to work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to upgrade to an Ada 2012 compiler to have the `'Result` attribute available.